# No module named _sqlite3 on python 3.9.2 virtual environment created with pyenv and poetry

Tags: python, sqlite, pyenv, python-poetry

I created a virtual environment with poetry as usual by running:

```
pyenv install 3.9.2
pyenv local 3.9.2
poetry env use 3.9.2
poetry install
poetry shell
```

I can effectively see a .python-version file where I can read "3.9.2" and python -V successfully returns 3.9.2. The virtual environment is activated too.

Should I delete the .venv folder and recreate the virtual environment. I do not quite understand why I am getting this error. I even ran

```
poetry add pysqlite3
poetry update
```

Comment: Here is the output of 
```poetry env info```
```Virtualenv
Python:         3.9.2
Implementation: CPython
Path:           /home/<>/projects/insta_analysis/.venv
Valid:          True

System
Platform: linux
OS:       posix
Python:   /home/<>/.pyenv/versions/3.9.2```
<> is a placeholder for the username

Comment: I noticed that if I run ```deactivate``` then it starts working, However, when I run ```poetry shell``` the error pops up again. Note that the output given by ```poetry env info``` after running both of the commands is the same. Maybe that helps